# Why can't I delete the SQLite database in Qt even after I call the database close function?

Tags: c++, sqlite, qt

I'm writing a code to work with a SQLite database, all the code of the database works, but at end, when I try to delete the database, the database file is not deleted. I've called the close function, so why can't I delete the database?
The db.isOpen(); function returns false, and the QFile::remove(path); returns false too.
Note: On Windows Explorer i can delete the database only after closing the program window.

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
QString path = "path_to_db";
db.setDatabaseName(path);

if(db.open())
{
    qDebug() << "Opened";
    qDebug() << path;
}
else
{
    qDebug() << db.lastError();
    return a.exec();
}
QSqlQuery query(db);

//code to work with the database

db.close();
qDebug() << db.isOpen();
qDebug() << QFile::remove(path);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, simply call `query.clear();` before close the connection.

Comment: Note that clear() does not have to be called, when you call db.close() after all queries have gone out of scope.

Comment: Niklas, i only got the database free after call the clear function, it is strange!